# wpf C# Hide / Show Controls in Resource File

Tags: c#, wpf

I am playing around with WPF for the first time and i am tring to show / hide group objects on a test toolbar based on a toggle button.

The toolbar is created via a template in a resource dictionary and i cannot figure out how to get this working as it seems alot more of an issue compared to winforms.

Out of all the examples i have found they all seem to function if the item is not templated is there any way i can acheive this.

my code so far is below and the point of failure is on the login togglebutton as i have x:name reference and apparently i cannot do this as its part of a resource dictionary, so i am pretty stumped...

```
                <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:wpfApplication1">

                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml"/>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Styles/ToolBar.xaml"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                    <ToolBar x:Key="MyToolbar" Height="120">
                        <ToolBar.Resources>
                            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis"/>   
                        </ToolBar.Resources>

                        <GroupBox x:Name="tBtn" Header="Login" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarGroup}" Margin="5,3,3,3">
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <!--Login-->
                                <ToggleButton  Margin="3" Width="55" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center""
                                        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTestApp}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Content>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/Login.png" Width="45"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="New" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ToggleButton.Content>
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox>

                        <GroupBox Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=tBtn, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}" Header="File" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarGroup}" Margin="5,3,3,3">
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <!--File-->
                                <Button  Margin="3" Width="55" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}"
                                        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTestApp}">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/GenericDocument.png" Width="45"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="New" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                                    <Button Margin="1" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}"
                                            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTestApp}">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/OpenFolder.png" Width="16"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,0" Text="Open" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Margin="1" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Save}"
                                            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTestApp}">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/Save.png" Width="16"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,0" Text="Save" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Margin="1" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Print}"
                                            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTestApp}">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/wpfApplication1;component/Resources/Images/Print.png" Width="16"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,0" Text="Print" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ResourceDictionary>
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

now your GroupBox is called "tBtn" but that should be your ToggleButton. (as you are refering to its property IsChecked)
Try to name your ToggleButton tBtn and retry

Comment: Hi sorry for delay that was a typo fir upload I tried moving it and I still receive an error regarding the use of name in a resource dictionary